# Any way to stop people from img "framing" your site?

Tags: hotlinking, attacks

Someone was trying to get cute with me, by "iframeing" my search result page via an IMG tag with 0 width and 0 height, in hopes of killing my server resources. My searches are cached, so it doesn't do much damage, since its just a static file being served, but I was wondering if there was anything I can do to "fight back"? I know you can use a frame breaker, had it been an iframe. Is there anything to do in the case of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering on referrer.  Either mod-rewrite or mod-security can be used.  See [Debain Administration](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/232) site for examples.

Comment: And then do what with it? It wont always send a referrer either.

Comment: If it's a hidden image, one could be reasonably sure the hits come from innocent third parties, and most of them send a referrer. Just filter / deny based on the specific domain or url misbehaving being present.

Comment: Is calling your search results page without a referrer a legitimate use case (for SEO reasons etc)? If not - block it.